# Using loops to take numbers giving it to list (feat Arrays)

Tags: c++, arrays, class, list

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

class NumberBox
{
private:

    int number;

public:

    NumberBox *next_ptr;
    void setNumber(int number)
    {
        this->number = number;
    }


    int getNumber()
    {
        return number;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int number[5];
    int counter;
    cout << "Please give 5 numbers" << endl;
    for(counter = 4; counter > - 1; counter--)
    {
        cin >> number[counter];
    }


    NumberBox *numberBoxListHead_ptr = new NumberBox();
    NumberBox *numberBoxListBody1_ptr = new NumberBox();
    NumberBox *numberBoxListBody2_ptr = new NumberBox();
    NumberBox *numberBoxListBody3_ptr = new NumberBox();
    NumberBox *numberBoxListTail_ptr = new NumberBox();

    numberBoxListHead_ptr->setNumber(number[4]);
    numberBoxListHead_ptr->next_ptr = numberBoxListBody1_ptr;

    if(numberBoxListHead_ptr->getNumber() == '5')
    {
        cout << "Outcome should be..." << endl;
    }
    numberBoxListBody1_ptr->setNumber(number[3]);
    numberBoxListBody1_ptr->next_ptr = numberBoxListBody2_ptr;
    if(numberBoxListHead_ptr->next_ptr->getNumber() == '5')
    {
        cout << "Use this as" << endl;
    }

    numberBoxListBody2_ptr->setNumber(number[2]);
    numberBoxListBody2_ptr ->next_ptr = numberBoxListBody3_ptr;
    if(numberBoxListBody1_ptr->next_ptr->getNumber() == '5')
    {
        cout << "Work" << endl;
    }

    numberBoxListBody3_ptr->setNumber(number[1]);
    numberBoxListBody3_ptr->next_ptr = numberBoxListTail_ptr;
    if(numberBoxListBody2_ptr->next_ptr->getNumber() == '5')
    {
        cout << "Please work" << endl;
    }

    numberBoxListTail_ptr->setNumber(number[0]);
    if(numberBoxListBody3_ptr->next_ptr->getNumber() == '5')
    {
        cout << "Work???" << endl;
    };

    getch();

}
```

For the finale, How can I make the "If Statement to work inside the list? Since I am gave the values that would have satisfy the If Statement", But it gives out blanks.

If I edit the node to send a number to satisfy the condition would that work?

Comment: please try to give minimalistic programs showing the problem

Comment: I don't know how to make this smaller.

Comment: You always call `getNumber` and never `setNumber`. If this is not a typo it is your error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `setNumber()` before you call `getNumber()` for each one.

```
numberBoxListHead_ptr->setNumber(number[0]);
numberBoxListHead_ptr->next_ptr = numberBoxListBody1_ptr;
cout << "The first number is " << numberBoxListHead_ptr->getNumber(number[0]) << endl;
```

Then repeat this for the other numbers.

In addition, you don't actually need the 'takenumber' parameter that is passed to getNumber() at all.

Answer (score 1):

`numberBoxListHead_ptr->getNumber(number[0]);` this doesn't do anything, you should use `setNumber` here. Also, your `getNumber` function should not take any arguments as it is not required. And, make `getNumber` a const member function.

Comment: I was confused by the nodes to pointers. Thanks!